# How does conda figure out the destination of each file?

Tags: conda

Each conda package has a `paths.json`, specifying all the files it contains. And it looks like this:

```
{
  "paths": [
    {
      "_path": "lib/python3.7/site-packages/fun-packge/__init__.py",
      "path_type": "hardlink",
      "sha256": "76f3b6e34feeb651aff33ca59e0279c4eadce5a50c6ad93b961c846f7ba717e9",
      "size_in_bytes": 2067
    },
    {
      "_path": "lib/python3.7/site-packages/fun-packge/__config__.py",
      "path_type": "hardlink",
      "sha256": "348e3602616c1fe4c84502b1d8cf97c740d886002c78edab176759610d287f06",
      "size_in_bytes": 87519
    },
    ...
}
```

My question is: this file only records where the files are located in the package itself. How does conda managed to figure out the destination of the file?

And for some softlink, where is the linked file? It only knows this path is a softlink.

```
    {
      "_path": "lib/icu/pkgdata.inc",
      "path_type": "softlink",
      "sha256": "ce1bdb3a6f5df26b30e155f42f027ed315118a245426057598ad030d1fa52fcc",
      "size_in_bytes": 1350
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative paths are the same both from the env being installed into and from the unzipped package in your package cache, so `_path` indicates both.  Visually, it's something like:

```
./miniconda3/
   |- pkgs/
   |   |- fun-package_v1.0_build2/
   |       |- lib/python3.7/site-packages/fun-package/
   |           |- __init__.py
   |           |- __config__.py
   |- envs/
       |- your_env
           |- lib/python3.7/site-packages/fun-package/
               |- __init__.py
               |- __config__.py
```

Comment: How about the softlink?

Comment: @youkaichao it's the same situation. Changing the link type doesn't affect the identity of the relative paths.

Comment: Uh, I see, as long as the softlink is linked to a directory in the package.